# Dividing a value between non-equal rows in order to balance them

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that's structured like:

```
Section        Total       Incoming     New Total
AK             56,445      2,655        59,100
AL             58,304      796          59,100
B              55,524      3,576        59,100
C              54,272      4,828        59,100
D              53,956      5,144        59,100
S              59,161      0            59,161
-
Generated Pts  16,999
```

I'm trying to automate the "Incoming" column. The goal of the sheet is to balance the Totals as closely as possible by distributing the Generated Pts between each row until no more points remain, ensuring that the lowest totals are always increased first so that higher values aren't increased while lower values exist.

Is this possible in a spreadsheet? Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: This is a [LP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) and can be solved with a couple of linear equations. Not sure if Google spreadsheets is a good tool for it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an attempt at a custom function. Two parameters are passed: the range corresponding with your Total column, and the cell containing the generated pts. Then the Incoming array is returned.

```
function distribute(range, value) {
  var indexedRange = range.map(function (e, index) {return [e[0], e[0], index];});
  indexedRange.sort(function (a, b) {return a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : 0;});
  var count = 0, i = 0, limit = indexedRange.length - 1;
  while (count < value) {
    indexedRange[i][0] ++;
    i = i == limit || indexedRange[i][0] <= indexedRange[i + 1][0] ? 0 : i + 1;
    count++;
  }
  indexedRange.sort(function (a, b) {return a[2] < b[2] ? -1 : a[2] > b[2] ? 1 : 0;});
  return indexedRange.map(function (e) {return [e[0] - e[1]];});    
}
```

It matches your expected results, but you might want to try it out on different data to check my logic is OK.

Comment: That's beautiful! I've tested it on my other sets and it works perfectly, thank you!